# Error using sigaction multiple times

Tags: c, linux, signals, fork, sigaction

I'm trying to call a function everytime my child process dies. This is done by catching the SIGCHLD sent by execve().
My problem here is that my handler function is not always called a second time. Sometimes it is though so I'm a bit confused.

My code is this one:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <signal.h> // sigaction()
  #include <time.h>
  #include <errno.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #define MAX_LENGTH 1000
  #define BILLION 1E9

  struct timespec start,stop;
  float totalTime = 0;

  void runCommand(int signo)
  {
    printf("Run command called\n");

    float processTime = 0;

    //Get the time when the process ended
    if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&stop) == -1){
      perror(NULL);
    }

    processTime = stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec + ( stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec ) / BILLION;
    totalTime += processTime;
  }


  int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    int counter = 0;
    int pid = 0;
    int status;
    char *args[4];
    char line[MAX_LENGTH];

    //Setup behaviour for SIGCHLD
    struct sigaction psa;
    psa.sa_handler = runCommand;
    sigaction(SIGCHLD, &psa, NULL);

    FILE *fp = fopen("script_file.txt","r");
    if(!fp)
    {
      return 0;
    }

    //Setup argsgcc
    args[0] = "/bin/sh";
    args[1] = "-c";
    args[3] = NULL;

    while(fgets(line, MAX_LENGTH, fp))
    {
      printf("The command number %d is %s \n", counter, line);

      //Get the time when the process started
      if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&start) == -1){
        perror(NULL);
      }

      //Create a new process
      pid = fork();

      //Child process
      if(pid == 0)
      {
        args[2] = line;
        execve("/bin/sh", args, NULL);
      }
      //Parent process
      else
      {
        wait(&status);
      }

      counter++;
    }

    printf("The overall time was %f seconds.\n", totalTime);

    fclose(fp);


    return 0;
  }
```

When I try to run it sometimes my result is:

```
The command number 0 is mkdir test/

Run command called
The command number 1 is sleep 0.5

Run command called
The command number 2 is sleep 1

Run command called
The command number 3 is rmdir test/

Run command called
The overall time was 1.544909 seconds.
```

Which seems correct.
But in other instances my result is:

```
The command number 0 is mkdir test/

Run command called
The command number 1 is sleep 0.5

The command number 2 is sleep 1

The command number 3 is rmdir test/

The overall time was 0.009810 seconds.
```

This makes me believe that sigaction is not always receiving my SIGCHLD signal.
When I run valgrind I get the following error:

```
    ==5407== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
    ==5407== 
    ==5407== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
    ==5407== 
    ==5407== 1 errors in context 1 of 2:
    ==5407== Syscall param rt_sigaction(act->sa_flags) points to uninitialised byte(s)
    ==5407==    at 0x4E6F5AE: __libc_sigaction (sigaction.c:62)
    ==5407==    by 0x40098B: main (iv.c:40)
    ==5407==  Address 0xffefff498 is on thread 1's stack
    ==5407==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
    ==5407==    at 0x400931: main (iv.c:29)
    ==5407== 
    ==5407== 
    ==5407== 1 errors in context 2 of 2:
    ==5407== Syscall param rt_sigaction(act->sa_mask) points to uninitialised byte(s)
    ==5407==    at 0x4E6F5AE: __libc_sigaction (sigaction.c:62)
    ==5407==    by 0x40098B: main (iv.c:40)
    ==5407==  Address 0xffefff4a8 is on thread 1's stack
    ==5407==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
    ==5407==    at 0x400931: main (iv.c:29)
    ==5407== 
    ==5407== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

But I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: You see that valgrind says uninitialized bytes, what do you think it means?

Comment: Put a `memset(&psa, 0, sizeof(psa));` just after the declaration and before initializing `sa_handler` field. And valgrind shall stop telling you that

Comment: "*`Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation [...] at 0x400931: main (iv.c:29)`*" have a look at `iv.c` line 29.

Comment: Thank you! Seems like it was just psa that needed to be initialized

Comment: `printf()` is not an async-signal-safe function and can't safely be used in a signal handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to initialise `psa` is to zero initialise it:

```
struct sigaction psa = {0};
```

However, there are subtleties. You can't call async-signal-unsafe functions, such as `printf`, from a signal handler. See [`signal safty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) for the list of allowed functions. You could replace the `printf` with a `write(2)` call to avoid this:

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Run command called\n", sizeof "Run command called\n" - 1);
```

Also you're performing `wait` on each of the child process before creating another. Thus there's always only one child running at any time. *If* you modify your program to allow multiple child processes to run simultaneously and the child processes die around the same, then not all `SIGCHLD` signals can be caught. For example, if a SIGCHLD arrives while the signal handler is processing is previous SIGCHLD, then it'll be lost. Because pending signals will be discarded unless they're *different* signals, except for real-time signals. For example, if `SIGUSR1` arrives while `SIGCHLD` is being processed (by signal handler), it'll be blocked; but another `SIGCHLD` will be ignored.